# Can a non-string variable come inside the handler of window.onerror event?

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

```
window.onerror = function() {
    log arguments.m || arguments[0];
}
```

I'm getting a log as '[Object event]'. Can anyone tell me why would there be an event object sent to the handler? and How can we reproduce or fix it?

and it's coming on android device's web control alone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well onerror *is* an event & non-IE browsers send an event object as an argument ...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but i'm printing arguments[0] which is supposed to be a message(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onerror) saying what the error is all about?

Comment: Yes, your correct it should be a string & it is for me http://jsfiddle.net/MCLgV/ is there anything else going on on the page

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error event object as the first argument for the function. The event object contains details about the error.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onerror mentions that the first argument is a message, the second is the url and the third is the line number which caused the javascript to fail

Answer (score 0):

`arguments` is not decided by how you define the function, but decided by how it is called.
When `window.onerror` is called, the `event` is passed to it as first parameter. (For non-IE, in IE, event is global accessable).

Example:

```
var foo = function() {
  console.log(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
}

foo(1,2);
// will log 1 and 2
```

​

Comment: But events are something that cannot be called and onerror is an event which gets triggered when javascript fails.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to simply be a bug in old Android browsers. See https://github.com/getsentry/raven-js/issues/360