# JavaScript [object Event] error on Android in GetSentry

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, runtime-error, sentry

I am using GetSentry for JavaScript error monitoring and I have an error, that I cannot find or cannot reproduce.

On many of my pages ([for example here](http://microsoft_excel.en.downloadastro.com/))
I have an error:

```
[object Event]
```

The error occurs (according to GetSentry) only on Android devices.

This error I cannot reproduce on my Android, or any other Androids here in the office.

Please provide some advice.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Getting the same error.

Comment: Nop, no idea... Just marked this as error's I cannot find.

Comment: we're getting those too, no backtrace, nothing to debug, not reproductible... Did you make any progress?

Comment: Getting this error as well. I think it is connected to a bug in the Android browser, on which Raven event tracking may not be working.

Comment: No fix yet, but related info:
Old browsers cause [object Event] to be logged · Issue #360 · getsentry/raven-js - https://github.com/getsentry/raven-js/issues/360
Can a non-string variable come inside the handler of window.onerror event? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563814/can-a-non-string-variable-come-inside-the-handler-of-window-onerror-event